# Extra pixel after CSS animation in top left corner of DIV

Tags: html, css

Having trouble diagnosing the cause of the floating pixel in the top left of the `div`. It only appeared once I added a `border-radius`.

Looking closely at each corner you can see some fragmenting as it applies the line before applying the radius. Perhaps a different technique all together is required.

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WgrvQL)

```css
.contest-types { 
 border: 2px solid #BCCED4;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: #1B2437;
 padding: 10px; 
 margin: 20px; 
 width: 500px; 
  height: 200px;
 background-color: #F9FDFF;
 position: relative;
}

.contest-types:before {
 content: '';
 width: 2px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: #5697fc;
 position: absolute;
 left: -2px;
 top: -2px;
 display: none;
}

.contest-types:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 background-color: #5697fc;
}

.contest-types:hover {
 border: 2px solid #5697FC;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 animation: border 0.5s ease-out 1;
}


.contest-types:hover:after {
  border-radius: 10px;
 animation: border-after 0.5s ease-in-out 1;
}

.contest-types:hover:before {
 display: block;
}

@keyframes border {
 0%, 24% {
  border-color: #BCCED4;
 }

 25% {
  border-top-color: #5697fc;
 }

 49% {
  border-right-color: #BCCED4;
 }

 50% {
  border-right-color: #5697fc;
 }

 74% {
  border-bottom-color: #BCCED4;
 }

 75% {
  border-bottom-color: #5697fc;
 }

 99% {
  border-left-color: #BCCED4;
 }

 100% {
  border-color: #5697fc;
 }
}

@keyframes border-after {
 0% {
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
 }

 24.99% {
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  height: 2px;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
 }

 25% {
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  top: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
 }

 49.99% {
  width: 2px;
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  top: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
 }

 50% {
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
 }

 74.99% {
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
 }

 75% {
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: auto;
  top: auto;
 }

 100% {
  width: 2px;
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: auto;
  top: auto;
 }
}
```

```html
      <div class="contest-types" id="group">

      </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `overflow: hidden`

```css
.contest-types { 
 border: 2px solid #BCCED4;
 border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
 color: #1B2437;
 padding: 10px; 
 margin: 20px; 
 width: 500px; 
  height: 200px;
 background-color: #F9FDFF;
 position: relative;
}

.contest-types:before {
 content: '';
 width: 2px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: #5697fc;
 position: absolute;
 left: -2px;
 top: -2px;
 display: none;
}

.contest-types:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 background-color: #5697fc;
}

.contest-types:hover {
 border: 2px solid #5697FC;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 animation: border 0.5s ease-out 1;
}


.contest-types:hover:after {
  border-radius: 10px;
 animation: border-after 0.5s ease-in-out 1;
}

.contest-types:hover:before {
 display: block;
}

@keyframes border {
 0%, 24% {
  border-color: #BCCED4;
 }

 25% {
  border-top-color: #5697fc;
 }

 49% {
  border-right-color: #BCCED4;
 }

 50% {
  border-right-color: #5697fc;
 }

 74% {
  border-bottom-color: #BCCED4;
 }

 75% {
  border-bottom-color: #5697fc;
 }

 99% {
  border-left-color: #BCCED4;
 }

 100% {
  border-color: #5697fc;
 }
}

@keyframes border-after {
 0% {
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
 }

 24.99% {
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  height: 2px;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
 }

 25% {
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  top: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
 }

 49.99% {
  width: 2px;
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  top: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  left: auto;
  bottom: auto;
 }

 50% {
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
 }

 74.99% {
  width: calc(100% + 2px);
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
 }

 75% {
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: auto;
  top: auto;
 }

 100% {
  width: 2px;
  height: calc(100% + 2px);
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  right: auto;
  top: auto;
 }
}
```

```html
      <div class="contest-types" id="group">

      </div>
```

Comment: That does fix the pixel but it also removes the animation itself. Now each side animates instantly. I was able to remove the extra pixel by removing `background-color: #5697fc;` from `.contest-types:after`. However, the animation itself still shows extra pixels for a single frame but only during animation. I can live with this. + 1 for your solution removing the stray pixel.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the animation is starting in the top left then changing to the square. You can either move the starting point or use overflow hidden to fix it.

```
.contest-types { 
    border: 2px solid #BCCED4;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #1B2437;
    padding: 10px; 
    margin: 20px; 
    width: 500px; 
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #F9FDFF;
    position: relative;
}
```